# Entity Framework WebApi Circular dependency serialization error

Tags: asp.net, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, circular-dependency

I think, I've read everything about this error and I tried everything. Here are my models:

Main:

```
public class Trip
{
    public int TripId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public float BasicPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApartmentType> ApartmentType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransportMethod> TransportMethod { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FeedingType> FeedingType { get; set; }
}
```

ApartmentType:

```
public class TransportMethod
{
    public int TransportMethodId { get; set; }
    public int TripId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

FeedingType:

```
public class FeedingType
{
    public int FeedingTypeId { get; set; }
    public int TripId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

TransportType:

```
public class TransportMethod
{
    public int TransportMethodId { get; set; }
    public int TripId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

When serializng the Trip entity I get a circular dependency error. Things i tried:

1. Disable lazy loading in DbContext.
2. Adding 
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling=Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All; to GLobal.asax
3. Adding a decorator [IgnoreDataMember] to TripId in every child entity.
4. Mapping this entity to a ViewModel which doesn't contain the ICollection members. - This worked ok, but at some point I will want to get those lists to the client.

I really don't know what's going on. What am I missing? I really can't spot any circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to the `TripId` to the children entities?

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm

or setting

`json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;`

Comment: Add it to the TripId in the children entities?

Comment: Same thing in both cases :/